# How to access the static list from one dart file to another in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter

### Situation

static list in `firstScreen.dart` as below

```
static List<Shoe> shoeBank = [
    Shoe(b: "Red Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct1.jpg", q: 0),
    Shoe(b: "White Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct2.jpg", q: 0)
  ];
```

this is the shoe class in `shoe.dart` file

```
class Shoe {
  String brand;
  int quantity;
  String image;
  Shoe({String b, int q, String i}) {
    brand = b;
    quantity = q;
    image = i;
  }
}
```

Now I want to use the `shoeBank` list in `secondScreen.dart` file.
*How to do this?*

### And also

I want to use the values of shoeBank while passing a parameter to the component `CheckOutItems` below in the `secondScreen.dart`

```
CheckoutItems(
addedToCartNumber:use of shoeBank Over here ,
checkOutScreenProductImage:use of shoeBank Over here,
shoesName:use of shoeBank Over here;
```

*How to do this?*

Comment: firstScreen.shoeBank.  Is there any other thing you are looking for

Comment: where you are using List<Shoe> shoeList = FirstScreen.shoeBank; means how you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply access the `static shoeBank` in the `SecondScreen` using `FirstScreen.shoeBank`.

I added an example below:

*Second Screen*

```
 class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {

   // access the static list using the class name
   List<Shoe> shoeList = FirstScreen.shoeBank;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // use the list here
     return CheckoutItems(
       // quantity
       addedToCartNumber: shoeList[0].quantity,
       // image
       checkOutScreenProductImage: shoeList[0].image,
       // shoe branch
       shoesName: shoeList[0].brand,
     );
   }
 }
```

*First Screen*

```
 class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   // shoe bank static list here
   static List<Shoe> shoeBank = [
    Shoe(b: "Red Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct1.jpg", q: 0),
    Shoe(b: "White Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct2.jpg", q: 0)
  ]; 

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
       
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: when used 
`List<Shoe> shoeList = FirstScreen.shoeBank;`
it gives an error like, The getter 'shoeBank' isn't defined for the type 'FirstScreen'

Comment: Can you update your question to show more details about this error? Everything works fine with the code I provided.

Comment: Now It worked, I had to make a getter in Firstscreen

Comment: when used this
`
return CheckoutItems(
       // quantity
       addedToCartNumber: shoeList[0].quantity,
       // image
       checkOutScreenProductImage: shoeList[0].image,
       // shoe branch
       shoesName: shoeList[0].brand,
     );
`
WHY DOES IT SHOW THIS ERROR?
see the comment below

Comment: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](1)

Comment: It was used to access the `first element` of the `shoeBank` list. Make sure your `shoeBank` list has items in it.

Comment: static List<Shoe> shoeBank = [
    Shoe(b: "Red Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct1.jpg", q: 0),
    Shoe(b: "White Shoe", i: "assets/nikeShoeProduct2.jpg", q: 0)
  ];
these are the items on it

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you are accessing the items and where you are doing that ?

Comment: There are items.
It gives an error stating, the method [ ] was called on null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219401/discussion-between-derek-and-aman-chaudhary).